# C++ OpenCV: write 4-channel float image

Tags: c++, opencv

Very simple question: is there a way/format to save an OpenCV float image with 4-channels (32FC4)? Or even better with an arbitrary number of channels?

`cv::imwrite()` with PFM/EXR extension is complaining that the image should have either 1 or 3 channels. 
I am aware that I could split the image and save each channel separately, however this is what I try to avoid.

I assume there must be another way which I just don't find.

Comment: Not near a machine to test, but check out TIFF as an option, if not through OpenCV's `imwrite()` then maybe via `libtiff` directly.

Comment: Great! That indeed seems to work, even directly with `imwrite()`. I am surprised that it is supported for tiff and not for the other float types. ( Well actually suprised that it doesn't work for all these float type images. )

Comment: Cool - good luck with your project.

Comment: By EXR extension are you referring to the [OpenEXR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenEXR) file format?

Comment: @WilliamMiller, yes exactly